# java.lang.NullPointerException under ui4j for one website

Tags: java

Its the second time i use ui4j, so i am not sure if i have done something wrong. i want to read a website so i have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    BrowserEngine webkit = BrowserFactory.getWebKit();

    // load the page
    Page page = webkit.navigate("http://www.okaa.gr/en/news-and-announcements/");
    page.show();

    // get the page
    Document document = page.getDocument();
}
```

This for some reason gives me this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>
> com.sun.javafx.Utils.getScreen(Unknown Source)    at
>
> com.sun.javafx.webkit.WebPageClientImpl.getScreenBounds(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.webkit.WCWidget.fwkGetScreenRect(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.webkit.Timer.twkFireTimerEvent(Native Method)    at
>   com.sun.webkit.Timer.fireTimerEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.webkit.Timer.notifyTick(Unknown Source)   at
>   javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PulseTimer.lambda$static$45(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PulseTimer$$Lambda$73/4280098.pulse(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$$Lambda$105/18919485.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$400(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$43/10413918.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
>   Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$39/30515573.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The same code with a different url works just fine.
I executed the ui4j ide and it loads the site ok. but still i cant get it to work on eclipse.

Comment: I assume this erros occurs, when you try to load a new URL but the WebView is not visible.

Comment: @ben honestly i have no recollection about this problem!!!! i either changed my system with out using ui4J, or i found some solution for it, but really I cant remember what i did. its been more than a month and  since then i had sooooo many problems that i lost count:) thanks for your interest.